# How to calculate the bytes trasnferred for file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Everyone,
            I want the total uploaded size of file in javascript..
I want to show the progress bar which shows the file uploaded size with the actual size of file

For Ex :-1800 B/3600 B....  (50 % Complete) ........ 3600 B/3600 B

How to calculate 1800 B i.e (file uploaded size)

I want only by using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for files uploading. Please look at the updateProgress() function

```
var formData = new FormData(),
  updateProgress = function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
          console.log('Uploading your document...', percentComplete);
      } else {
          // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
      }
    };



  formData.append('file', file);

  $.ajax({
      url: '/upload-file',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,
      processData: false, // Don't process the files
      contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
      success: function(successResponse) {
        console.log(successResponse);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
          console.log('error', xhr);
      },
      xhr: function() { // custom xhr
          var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
          if (myXhr.upload) { // check if upload property exists
              myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
          }
          return myXhr;
      },
      complete: function() {

      }
  });
```

Or if you don't want to use jQuery:

```
const xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (evt) => {
  let percentComplete = null;
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
  }
  console.log('progress', percentComplete);
}, false);
xhr.addEventListener('load', (evt) => {
  console.log('done');
}, false);
xhr.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
  console.log('error');
}, false);
xhr.addEventListener('abort', (event) => {
  console.log('abort');
}, false);

xhr.open('POST', 'http://example.com/upload', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

UPD:
If evt.lengthComputable is false, then you need to set Content-Length header of the XMLHttpRequest to value of file.size

```
$.ajax({
            ...
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", file.size);
            },
             ....
});
```

Comment: But the evt.loaded is becoming greater than even evt.total means let us suppose  my file size is 7718031 bytes but its uploading 77191813 which exceeds the actual file size

Comment: what is e.total? Alexey

Comment: evt is an instance of ProgressEvent. As per the docs, total "Is an unsigned long long representing the total amount of work that the underlying process is in the progress of performing" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent

Comment: But the evt.loaded is becoming greater than even evt.total

Comment: Check evt.lengthComputable If it's false, then you need to set Content-Length header of the XMLHttpRequest to value of file.size.  I'm gonna update my answer now

Comment: I have checked evt.lengthComputable  is true e.loaded and e.total both are becoming the same value

Comment: if e.loaded is equal to e.total, then your file is uploaded, isn't it?

Comment: what I mean is that the uploaded file size is 7718031 bytes but e.total and e.loaded is showing as 7719838 bytes so my concern is that my it's exceeding more than its actual file size..?